# How do I look at column of syscolumns in sybase?

Tags: sap-iq

I am trying to get schema of existing database using this query in sybase iq 15.4 -

```
SELECT t.name AS TABLE_NAME, col.name AS column_name
FROM sysobjects t 
JOIN syscolumns col ON t.id=col.id
WHERE t.TYPE='U'
```

I am getting an error "syscolumns is ambigous" so I resolved this error by changing the syntax -

```
SELECT t.name AS TABLE_NAME, col.name AS column_name
    FROM sysobjects t 
    JOIN sys.syscolumns col ON t.id=col.id
    WHERE t.TYPE='U'
```

After that I am getting an error "Column id not found". Can you please help me to use this query to get the column for join on other column.

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use this query as -

```
SELECT t.name AS TABLE_NAME, col.cname AS column_name
        FROM sysobjects t 
        JOIN sys.syscolumns col ON t.name =col.tname
        WHERE t.TYPE='U'
```